# Override slide on jssor next prev buttons to use fade instead of slide

Tags: jssor

Jssor image slider automatically uses the slide for arrow navigation. Is it possible to make it use Fade?

I have:

```
    $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
},
```

which uses _SlideshowTransitions which have duration and opacity for fade but this affects only Autoplay transitions and not arrow transitions.

in ArrowNavigatorOptions is there anything I can add to make the next prev arrow transitions of images Fade?

```
    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                                                                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about any plugin? Make your question more clear.

Comment: JSSOR is an image slider plugin which has a tag already created for it so it should be clear that it is javascript or jquery slider as per the popup when you move your mouse over the Jssor tag
So why did you delete Jssor, which is a valid tag, from the title and make it non understandable to everyone who knows what jssor is?

Comment: I will consider this feature. For now, it always slides left<->right according to manual manual navigation request.

Comment: I have just discovered Cycle2 Jquery plugin which will do everything I need it to so no need to do anything at my suggestion.